# System.MissingMethocException on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: exception, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After updating my Xamarin.Forms package, It has started to crash at the beginggin of the app launch.

It says ; Method.Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.SimpleValueTargetProvider..ctor not found.

How can I fix it?

I have tried cleaning, restarting Xamarin Studio and Rebuilding. But no success, still getting exception.

Could you please show me the way?

BR,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms - XamlCompilation MissingMethodException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278762/xamarin-forms-xamlcompilation-missingmethodexception)

Answer (score 0):

If your app doesn't depend on any 3rd party Xamarin.Forms component compiling it's xaml with XamlC, you can fix your problem by making sure ALL your projects are up-to-date with latest Xamarin.Forms.

If you depend on a 3rd party project distributed to you as an assembly, the problem is known:

- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48105

and a solution exists:

- https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/583

This should be included in a service release in the next few days.